# How to access a webservice requiring certificate

Tags: web-services

I need to make a webservice call using C# to a webservice requiring SSl certificate.I have the cert file, and installed it.When,I browse to https url,it requests for a certificate(but no certs visible).
How to do call webservice in code? Do I have to install the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it is for the older framework but still works)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/901183